# Run periodic celery task with a dynamic schedule in django application

Tags: django, celery, django-celery, django-celery-beat

I am wondering if it is possible to have my end users dynamically adjust the schedule of a periodic task.

So something along these lines:

```
# celery.py

def get_schedule():
    config = get_user_config()  # returns a model object of sorts
    return config.frequency_in_seconds

app.conf.beat_schedule = {
    'my_periodic_task': {
        'task': 'my_periodic_task',
        'schedule': get_schedule,  # schedule updated based on `get_schedule` function
    },
}
```

This way, if a user were to change the `frequency_in_seconds` field in their user config setting, it would dynamically update the beat schedule.

My preference would be to do this outside of the Django Admin site and without any additional packages (e.g. django-celery-beat).

Any thoughts or ideas would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you're using django, you can use [django-celery-beat](https://pypi.org/project/django-celery-beat/) to allow end-users to control the schedule using the django admin panel.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, but I was hoping to accomplish this without django-celery-beat, as mentioned above.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using redis as your result backend, you can use this library here https://github.com/parad0x96/django-redbeat

- 1. Create the dynamic periodic task.:

```
from django_redbeat import PeriodicTaskEntry

task = PeriodicTasksEntry.objects.create(
       name="The verbose name of the task",
       task="yourapp.tasks.task_name",
       args=[arg1, arg2,],
       schedule=10# the schedule in seconds
)
```

This will create a dynamic periodic task, which you have control on the schedule and the creation as well.

- 2. Run Celery beat like this :

`celery -A your_app_name beat -l INFO -S redbeat.RedBeatScheduler --max-interval 10`